# Get the Unicode code point of a character in zsh

Tags: zsh, string, unicode

How can I get the Unicode code point of a character in zsh?

e.g., if I have:

```
s=abc
```

How can I get the code point of `s[2]` (i.e. code point of `"b"` = `0x0062`)?

Comment: Does it have to be in zsh? You can just create a script file and put `python3 -c "print(ord(u'b'))"` into it. BTW, the Unicode for 'b' is 98.

Comment: @Quora Feans: I want it to be in zsh since my shell is zsh, and I don't want to have any other dependencies.  0062 in hex == 98 in decimal; I prepended `0x` in my question to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexing is done with ${s:start:length}, and then converted to hexadecimal using printf with %x. You can do further formatting with printf if you like.

```
printf '%x\n' "'${s:1:1}'"
```

Comment: `%x` converts `'b` to a code point. The single quote is what makes it work. Indexing doesn't have to be done with `${s:1:1}`, `$s[2]` works just fine.

Comment: Is there any difference between `printf '%04x\n' "'${s[2]}'"` & `printf "%04x\n" "'${s[2]}'"`? (single vs. double quotes around first argument)  I get the same output for the 2

Comment: @XDR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Answer (score 2):

You can get it through the [`printf` builtin](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-printf).

> With the numeric format specifiers, if the corresponding argument starts with a quote character, the numeric value of the following character is used as the number to print

To store the code point in a numeric variable:

```
printf -v code_point %d \'$s[2]
```

To print out the code point in hexadecimal notation:

```
printf '%04x\n' \'$s[2]
```

Comment: Running either of those commands in zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0) on macOS Catalina 10.15.1 results in 0, either 0 stored in `code_point`, or `0000` output to the console.  But `0x0062` should be output.

Comment: I think `$s[2]` needs to be `"'$s[2]'"`, though I'd use `"'${s[2]}'"`

Comment: @XDR Indeed I'd forgotten the quotes in the example. On the other hand I see no reason to put braces. They're just visual noise. And you only need a quote before the character, not after.